# Unable to get the desired result array

Tags: javascript, arrays, momentjs

I am currently learning lodash and moment.js and I'm using some dummy data.The dummy data that contains a list of 1000 doctors.I have started working with **Array.prototype.map()** and **Array.prototype.filter()** and will be converting them to lodash soon.

data

```
var doctors = [
  {
    "id": 0,
    "dateOfEmployment": "2012-12-27",
    "dateOfTermination": "2015-01-13",
    "dateOfBirth": "1978-06-06",
    "gender": "Male"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "dateOfEmployment": "2016-02-08",
    "dateOfTermination": null,
    "dateOfBirth": "1984-04-21",
    "gender": "Female"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "dateOfEmployment": "2010-11-30",
    "dateOfTermination": "2015-09-03",
    "dateOfBirth": "1975-09-24",
    "gender": "Male"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "dateOfEmployment": "2012-06-17",
    "dateOfTermination": null,
    "dateOfBirth": "1980-08-31",
    "gender": "Female"
  },..];
```

I would like to get a result of array for the last 2 years:

```
[{ date: '2015-04', count: 22 }, 
 { date: '2015-05', count: 25 },
 ...]
```

Initially I tried this:

```
    doctors = doctors.filter(function(doctor){
             return moment(doctor.dateOfEmployment).isBetween('2014-04', '2016-04');   
          }).map(function(doctor){
              return  {
            dates: moment(doctor.dateOfEmployment).format('YYYY-MM'),
            count: new Date(doctor.dateOfEmployment) - new Date(doctor.dateOfEmployment) + 1 };
      }););


console.log(doctors);
```

I am confused. Should I first create a new array of doctors with just **id**, **dateOfEmployment**, **dateOfTermination** and momentize both dates. Then filter the new date array with a condition where moment isBetween the years and then map/reduce.

I did think of brute-force method where I would loop through 24 times on each doctor and increment a counter based on the condition that if **doctorsEmployment** date and **doctorsTermination** date is either null or equal to the temporary date.The temporary date starting from '2014-04' to '2016-04' and finally pushing it to array the result object.

Am I approaching this problem in a wrong way?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I feel like this is more of a *reduce* operation than a *filter / map*.

Comment: instead of the mapping, try this: `_.groupBy(filteredArray, doctor => moment(doctor.dateOfEmployment).format('YYYY-MM'))`

Comment: As Phil says, you're creating an array with *filter*, then going over that and creating another array with *map*. Using *reduce* will allow you to do both in one iteration to create one array. It's probably also much more efficient to convert the date strings to dates before calling the function, otherwise you are also creating new Dates or moment.js instances on every loop.

Comment: The result of `new Date(doctor.dateOfEmployment) - new Date(doctor.dateOfEmployment)` will be either *NaN* or zero.

Answer (score 1):

Not lodash or moment.js, but here's how to do it in plain JS:

```js
// Sample data
var doctors = [
  {
    "id": 0,
    "dateOfEmployment": "2012-12-27",
    "dateOfTermination": "2015-01-13",
    "dateOfBirth": "1978-06-06",
    "gender": "Male"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "dateOfEmployment": "2016-02-08",
    "dateOfTermination": null,
    "dateOfBirth": "1984-04-21",
    "gender": "Female"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "dateOfEmployment": "2016-02-29",
    "dateOfTermination": "2015-09-03",
    "dateOfBirth": "1975-09-24",
    "gender": "Male"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "dateOfEmployment": "2015-06-17",
    "dateOfTermination": null,
    "dateOfBirth": "1980-08-31",
    "gender": "Female"
  }];
 
// Parse ISO date string (e.g. 2016-04-01) as local
function parseISODate(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  return new Date(b[0], b[1]? b[1] - 1 : 0, b[2] || 1);
}

var startDate = parseISODate('2014-04'),
    endDate   = parseISODate('2016-04');

// Creates an object with months and counts
var resultObj = doctors.reduce(function(acc, cur) {
  var d = parseISODate(cur.dateOfEmployment);
  if (d >= startDate && d <= endDate) {
    var month = d.toISOString().slice(0,7);
    acc[month] = (acc[month] || 0) + 1;
  }
  return acc;
}, {});

// Creates an array with required objects from result object
var resultArr = Object.keys(resultObj).map(function(key) {
  return {date: key, count: resultObj[key]};
})
 
document.write(
  JSON.stringify(resultObj) + '<br>' + // {"2016-02":2,"2015-06":1}
  JSON.stringify(resultArr)  // [{"date":"2016-02","count":2},{"date":"2015-06","count":1}]
);
```

This assumes you only want months that have a count greater than zero. It goes through the original data once, then the result object once, though I can't see how the array is a more desirable format than the object it's created from.

Note that I edited the source data to have two *dateOfEmployment* dates in February, 2016.

Answer (score 0):

how just using lodash's reduce...something like this:

```
var doctors = [{
  "id": 0,
  "dateOfEmployment": "2014-12-27",
  "dateOfTermination": "2015-01-13",
  "dateOfBirth": "1978-06-06",
  "gender": "Male"
}, {
  "id": 1,
  "dateOfEmployment": "2016-02-08",
  "dateOfTermination": null,
  "dateOfBirth": "1984-04-21",
  "gender": "Female"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "dateOfEmployment": "2015-11-30",
  "dateOfTermination": "2015-09-03",
  "dateOfBirth": "1975-09-24",
  "gender": "Male"
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "dateOfEmployment": "2012-06-17",
  "dateOfTermination": null,
  "dateOfBirth": "1980-08-31",
  "gender": "Female"
}];

doctors = _.reduce(doctors, function(memo, doctor) {
  if (moment(doctor.dateOfEmployment).isBetween('2014-04', '2016-04')) {
    memo.push({
      dates: moment(doctor.dateOfEmployment).format('YYYY-MM'),
      count: new Date(doctor.dateOfEmployment) - new Date(doctor.dateOfEmployment) + 1
    });
  }
  return memo;
}, []);
console.log(doctors);
```

working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1qtLb3cb/1/)

Comment: Note that this does not collate a count of the *dateOfEmployment* in the same month, it creates a new object for each so `[{dates:'2016-02', count:1}, {dates:'2016-02': count: 1}]` rather than `[{dates:'2016-02', count:2}]`. Also *dates* not *date* (minor quibble…). ;-)